# Printable type string from parameter

Tags: objective-c, clang

Using clang and objective-c I'm wondering if I can get a printable string describing the type of a potentially null parameter (i.e. compile time only type information.)

For example something like:

```
- (void)myFunc:(NSString *)aNilString {
    NSLog(@"%s", __typeof__(aNilString));
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because __typeof__ gets me the actual type, not a string. In C++ we have typeid which returns a std::type_info, but that name is mangled, e.g. "P12NSString*" and not "NSString*".

Ideally I'd like something that can be passed into functions like objc_getClass(). Is there a way to get what I want?

Edit: I'd like not to have to compile as C++, so this solution is out:

```
abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(*aNilString).name(), 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a string that can be passed into functions like objc_getClass() just use the description of the class object.

In this example, I changed the type of your argument from `NSString *` to `id` since if you already knew that the argument was an `NSString *` then this question would be kind of moot.  Note that I call the `class` method of the object being passed in and then the `description` method of the class in order to get an `NSString *` which describes the class and can be used with the methods that you reference.

Note also that if the object is `nil` then there is no class and calling `description` will simply return nil and the `NSLog` will print `(null)`.  You can't determine the type of pointer at runtime because it is simply a pointer to a class object (and that doesn't exist for `nil`).

```
- (void)myFunc:(id)aClassObject {
    // Get the description of aClassObject's class:
    NSString *classString = [[aClassObject class] description];
    NSLog(@"%@", classString); // Prints __NSCFConstantString

    // Bonus:  Get a new object of the same class   
    if ([classString length] > 0) {
        id theClass = objc_getClass([classString UTF8String]);
        id aNewObjectOfTheSameType = [[theClass alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@", [[aNewObjectOfTheSameType class] description]); // Prints __NSCFConstantString
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with all the obj runtime goodness.

I know that technically the type is known, so this should be trivial, however, to cut a long story short, this function is generated by a sequence of macros making getting the parameter's type more difficult than you'd think, hence the question.

Comment: If you're generating the code, @Tim, why isn't it possible to just generate one more copy of the type name? `[ClassName class]` will get you the class object even if the method gets `nil` passed in.

Comment: That's ultimately what I've done. I just thought it was an interesting question.